# Simplest Way to Trim All String within a List<string[]> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List <string[]>`.

What is the simplest way to trim all strings using **LINQ**?

Comment: Do you mean to have a List of String arrays?

Comment: Yes. I got this from SqlDataReader.

Comment: If you want to modify the existing collection, just use `foreach` and a `for` loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LINQ is for querying, It shouldn't be used for modifying existing collection. You can use the following, but it will return a new collection.

```
List<string[]> newList = list.Select(outer => outer
                .Select(innerItem => innerItem.Trim())
                .ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

You may add checking against `Null` for each element in the string array before calling `Trim` to avoid NRE. Something like:

```
.Select(innerItem => innerItem != null ? innerItem.Trim() : null)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the original signature is correct it should be

```
var result = original
    .Select( x=> 
        x.Select(y => y.Trim())
         .ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

where x is each array of Strings in the original list, and y is the member from the inner array.